# Python - Write literal \n to file

Tags: python, file, io, newline

I'm trying to write some text to a file in python, however I'm running into a problem with the following line

```
<ClCompile Include="..\src\node\Node.cpp" />
```

It seems that python is interpreting the \n in \node as a new line. I need to solve this problem while still maintaining the actual new lines in the file.

**EDIT**

Upon further investigation it seems that this is being caused by a regex substitution call that I'm making.

A summarized version is a follows:

```
mainString = mainFile.read() 
compileRegex = re.compile(ur'(<ClCompile(.*/>\n)*)')
compileMatch = compileRegex.search(mainString)
compileString = compileMatch.group(1) 
tempFileString = tempFile.read()
tempFileString = re.sub(compileRegex, compileString, tempFileString)
```

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. I don't know where you see `\n`.

Comment: @Malik Brahimi: It's in the string. Look again and you'll find `\N` **and** `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **raw strings**

```
In [1]: r".\n."
Out[1]: '.\\n.'
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm reading the string from a file and performing regex operations on it. Is there a way to get this to work as a raw string. I've tried escaping the back slashes with double backslashes but it doesn't seem to make a difference. My code is as follows https://gist.github.com/RyanBluth/ac25372b38bb761edf2a

Comment: A read file is already literal. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I saw that when doing some research as well, however it doesn't solve my issue, meaning something else is going on. Perhaps its a problem with the  regex substitution that I'm doing?